# VB Code not working in excel

Tags: excel, encoding, vba

Hello I'm trying to get an answer to a pretty basic question but I'm trying to make it work in excel
I need the program to display the correct answer on screen at the moment it keeps coming up with 2
my code is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer

Dim A1 As Integer

Dim A2 As Integer

Dim Ans As Integer

i = 1

A1 = 31.2928

A2 = 22.352

If (((A1 * i) / 2)) > (A2 * i) Then

Ans = i

Else

        i = i + 1

End If

Ans = i

MsgBox "Value is" & Ans

End Sub
```

I want it to come up with the correct answer to the above statement 
I want the program to times A1 by i and then divide it by 2 and then see if its bigger than A2 times i and loop around the program until a number is found

Comment: `31.2928` is not an integer and that is not VB.NET code.  Please read [ask] and also take the [tour]

Comment: its an old plain VB right? @plutonix is right, those number is not integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first set `A1` to 31 and `A2` to 22.  You then calculate `(((31 * 1) / 2)) > (22 * 1)` which equates to `False`.  (It would do so even if you calculated  `(((31.2928 * 1) / 2)) > (22.352 * 1)`.)  Because it is `False` you set `i` to be `i + 1` which is `2`.  You then set `Ans = i`, so `Ans` is now 2.

I believe what you want is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim A1 As Double
    Dim A2 As Double
    Dim Ans As Integer
    i = 1
    A1 = 31.2928
    A2 = 22.352
    Do
        If (((A1 * i) / 2)) > (A2 * i) Then
            Ans = i
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Value is " & Ans

End Sub
```

However, because `31.2928 * i /2` will never exceed `22.352 * i` (because 15.6464 < 22.352), I would recommend you don't run that code because it will crash out once `i` reaches 32767 and gives an overflow error.

Note: An equation of the form `(a * i) > (b * i)` is equivalent to `a > b` (after dividing both sides by the common value `i`) so the answer will be `True` or `False` irrespective of the value of `i` *(assuming positive values of `i`)*.